# Transfer objects to modal window angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to transfer object in modal windows, i had tried  in  this way

```
$scope.OpenMessage = function (res) {
 var modalInstance = $uiModal.open({
   size: 'sm',
   windowClass: 'modal-xs',
   templateUrl: 'views/message.html',
   controller: 'SearchCtrl',
   resolve: {
     items: function () {
       return res;
     }
   }
 });
};
```

but when i try to output in html {{res}} it shows empty

Comment: show the controller and html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your data in modal by using `items.res`, remember to inject `items` dependency in your modal controller.

Hope this helps